# Appending to dictionary with same key, multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, defaultdict

Trying to understand what the best idea/practice here would be.. I have a dataframe with interviewers at various locations.. I would like to create a dictionary or some sort of data structure that holds the interviewers name and then every coordinate point we have for their interview. An example of the dataframe I am working with is something like this:

```
    interview       longitude        latitude
1   A1                  34.2             90.2
2   A1                  54.2             23.5
6   A1                  NaN              NaN
7   A2                  NaN              NaN
8   A2                  NaN              NaN
9   A2                  23.1             38.2
10  A2                  -23.7            -98.4
```

I would like to essentially have a dictionary that has 'A1' and it holds (34.2, 90.2), (54.2, 23.5) and 'A2' would hold (23.1, 39.2), (-23.7, -98.4).

```
    location_dict = {}
    for name, group in df.groupby('Interviewer'):
        minidf = group[['Interviewer','Longitude','Latitude']].dropna()
        for index, row in minidf.iterrows():
            location_dict[name]=(row['Longitude'], row['Latitude'])
```

My logic here is a bit off, but I don't have any way to 'append' to a dictionary, so my dictionary is only outputting the data from last iteration of iterrows... How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: You are now storing a single tuple as the value. Try to extrapolate from there a bit; a tuple is a container just like a dictionary is a container. Know of any other containers that you could use to hold multiple tuples?

Comment: Put differently: you need to pick a container type for the dictionary values, to store those multiple tuples in. A dictionary just maps keys to values, but those values can be *any type of Python object*, including tuples, other dictionaries, and more.

Comment: Should I put all the tuples into a list, and then add them to Interviewer key?

Comment: For an interviewer key, add a list to the dictionary *if the key isn't in the dictionary yet*. If the key is in the dictionary already, just append to the list that is there.

Comment: You can test, add a list if it is not there yet, and append to the list, in one step with `location_dict.setdefault(name, []).append((row['Longitude'], row['Latitude']))`.

Answer (score 4):

One solution using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
def zipper(row):
    return list(zip(row['longitude'], row['latitude']))

res = df.dropna(subset=['longitude', 'latitude'])\
        .groupby('interview').apply(zipper).to_dict()

# {'A1': [(34.2, 90.2), (54.2, 23.5)],
#  'A2': [(23.1, 38.2), (-23.7, -98.4)]}
```

Another using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for row in df.dropna(subset=['longitude', 'latitude']).itertuples(index=False):
    res[row.interview].append((row.longitude, row.latitude))
```

Since `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, in general no further manipulation is required.